# How to see changes in catch in try block?

Tags: java, try-catch

I am trying to create a try and catch statement, but I have problems with scopes, the changes that I make in catch statement don't appear once I get back to try. Is there any way around this? I am giving the example:

```
int num_fails = 0;
int num_tries = 0;
while(true) {
    try {
        num_tries++;
        some_function();
        if (num_tries > num_fails)
            break; 
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        num_fails++;
    }
}
```

When exception happens, num_fails in if statement stays 0.

Comment: That does not appear to be possible. Are you completely sure this is the program you are running? (also, if the error is thrown by your `some_function()` then the if-statement is never run)

Comment: I'm confused as well. I don't know why it goes to try statement once the exception has been caught, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You should not have the chance to execute `some_function` more than 1 time if `some_function` doesn't throw any exception as `num_tries` is 1 and `num_fails` is 0 and then break the while loop. To let the while loop run, `some_function` should always throw exceptions.

If `some_function` always throws exceptions, or errors(note: Error is not a subclass of Exception, can't be caught by this try-catch), then I don't think the description of the problem is true.

Answer (score 0):

`catch` block will execute whenever there is an Exception, however in the example you have given there is no exception unless `some_function()`
throws an Exception. If not,

`catch` block will not be executed.

cause, the condition in the if statement will be true and the while loop will break.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the problem is in num_tries not being updated. Rather, it is the sequence of your code.

```
if (num_tries > num_fails)
      break;
```

The above code will never be executed and your loop won't break since if there is an exception, it will go to your catch block.

Comment: My problem is that it actually goes back to try statement.

Comment: Then it could mean there is really no exception caught.

Comment: “goes back to try statement” is a different way to describe precisely what this answer says, the `if` statement is not executed and since it’s a loop, it will end up at the beginning of the `try` statement.